# SET in combination with CASE statement in cypher

Tags: neo4j, case, cypher

I am tryin to set two different relationship properties to a count, with a case construct depending on the value of another relationship property. There is a console at  http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rt1ld5

the cnt column contains the number of times r.value occurs. The two first rows of the initial query in the console indicate that the term "Car" is linked to 1 document that is considered relevant, and to two documents that are considered not relevant.

I want to SET a property on the [:INTEREST] relation between  (user) and (term) with two properties, indicating how many times an interest is linked to a document that is considered relevant or not. So for (John)-[r:INTEREST]->(Car) I want r.poscnt=1 and r.negcnt=2

I.m struggling with the CASE construct. I tried various ways, this was the closest I got.

```
MATCH (u:user)-[int:INTEREST]->(t:term)<-[:ISABOUT]-(d:doc)<-    [r:RELEVANCE]-(u)
WITH int, t.name, r.value, count(*) AS cnt
CASE
  WHEN r.value=1 THEN SET int.poscnt=cnt
  WHEN r.value=-1 THEN SET int.negcnt=cnt
END
```

But it's returning an error

```
Error: Invalid input 'A': expected 'r/R' (line 3, column 2)
"CASE"
  ^
```

Comment: For anyone curious, to resolve the error above place a comma after 'cnt'. There are other errors in the query but hopefully that'll get you closer to solving the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did it!  Also see console at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rq2i7j

```
MATCH (u:user)-[int:INTEREST]->(t:term)<-[:ISABOUT]-(d:doc)<-[r:RELEVANCE]-(u)
WITH int, t, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN r.value= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS poscnt, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN r.value= -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS negcnt
SET int.pos=poscnt,int.neg=negcnt
RETURN t.name,int.pos,int.neg
```

Comment: Following this syntax, I am writing a query someting like this :


**match (node) where node.label="ParameterSetter" or node.label="Parameter" with node order by node.thread_id,node.event_seq_no with node,head(node) as firstNode,sum(case when firstNode.label="ParameterSetter" then 0 else 1) as firstIndex**

It is giving me error message **mismatched input 'when' expecting ';'** at case clause. Am I missing something?

Comment: this works : 


    match (node) where node.label="ParameterSetter" or 
    node.label="Parameter" 
    with node order by node.thread_id,node.event_seq_no 
    with head(collect(node)) AS firstNode
    with 
         sum(case when firstNode.label="ParameterSetter" then 0 else 1 end) 
         as firstIndex
    return *

Answer (score 3):

Is it important for you to keep positive and negative count separate? It seems you could have a `score` property summing positive and negative values.

```
MATCH (u:user)-[int:INTEREST]->()<-[:ISABOUT]-()<-[r:RELEVANCE]-(u)
SET int.score = SUM(r.value)
RETURN t.name, int.score
```

You already seem to have found a working solution but I'll add a note about `CASE` as I understand it. While `CASE` provides branching, I think it's correct to say that it is an expression and not a statement. It resembles a ternary operator more than a conditional statement.
As the expression

```
a > b ? x : y;
```

is resolved to a value, either `x` or `y`, that can be used in a statement, so also

```
CASE WHEN a > b THEN x ELSE y END
```

resolves to a value. You can then assign this value

```
result = CASE WHEN a > b THEN x ELSE y END
```

Your original query used the `CASE` expression like a conditional statement

```
CASE WHEN a > b THEN result = x ELSE result = y END
```

which resembles if-else

```
if a > b { result = x; } else { result = y; }
```

Someone may want to correct the terminology, the point is that in your working query you correctly let `CASE` resolve to a value to be used by `SUM` rather than put a conditional assignment inside `CASE`.

Comment: It took me some time before I understood the way CASE is used in cypher, so thanks for the additional explanation. And, yes keeping them separate is important, because it's not yet clear how the results will be processed further. Just using the sum would hide the difference between pos:50 / neg:49  and pos:2/neg: 1

Comment: "Let `CASE` resolve to a value, rather than put a conditional assignment inside `CASE`" — this is perfectly succinct, thank you.