# set propery depending on a condition in a cypher request

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a cypher request but I do not understand how I can set a property depending on a condition. My current request is like the following :

```
"MATCH (p:Picto{uuid : {pictoUuid}}) OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:PICTO_OF]->(e:Element) SET p.deleted = true, e.deleted = true"
```

What I want to do is set "e.deleted=true" only if all picto of an element have deleted property equals to true.

I think there is something to do like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459893/set-in-combination-with-case-statement-in-cypher) but I do not understand how to achieve that.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query work for you? It marks the specified `Picto` as deleted, and then checks if all the `Pictos` associated with its `Element` (if any) have been marked deleted. If so, it then marks that `Element` deleted as well.

```
MATCH (p:Picto{uuid : {pictoUuid}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:PICTO_OF]->(e:Element)
SET p.deleted = TRUE
WITH e
MATCH (x)-[:PICTO_OF]->(e)
WITH e, COLLECT(x) AS pictos
WHERE ALL(p IN pictos WHERE p.deleted = TRUE)
SET e.deleted = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works well after a little change to fix the error "Cannot add labels or properties on a node which is already bound". Indeed you can't repeat the type of 'e' (e:Element) in the second MATCH.

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks. Also, please don't forget to up-vote my answer.